# automatically change the “fcc:” field with the sender when composing mails in neomutt

Tags: mutt, neomutt

when i compose a message in neomutt, the “fcc:” field is set by, i presume, the `record` variable in my configuration; now i can

- manually change this field when composing the message using `edit-fcc` (which bound to `f` by default), and
- have it be changed automatically depending on the *recipient* of the message i’m composing (using an `fcc-hook`).

however i have found no way to have this field changed automatically depending on the *sender* of the message i’m composing, that is when changing the “from:” field.

is there a way to do so?

it seems like a very basic function. the typical use case is for people with multiple accounts who sort their outgoing messages by account. one starts composing a message and later on decides from which account to send the message using the `edit-from` command. clearly, one now wants the “fcc:” field to be updated automatically instead of invoking `edit-fcc` manually as well.

i know there is a hook, the `send2-hook`, for having neomutt execute any command i wish whenever i change the message - but i see no command to change the “fcc:” field of the message i’m currently composing. setting the `record` variable anew using `send2-hook` works, but unfortunately its value *does not* override the already-set “fcc:” field and it’s the latter that has precedence for neomutt when saving outgoing mails.